# Automatic redirection in Angular

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I have an application that has some automatic redirection that are not invoked by user, but by some third party event driver and this is ok in most cases.

Problem comes when application is not in focus. Expected behaviour would be to just do first next redirection after it goes in focus, but instead it looks like it is fast-forwarding all redirections that have occurred during the time application was out of focus.

For example I have

```
$scope.$on('some_event', function () {
    $state.go(someState);
});
```

Is there any way to drop those redirection that have occurred during the time application was off focus?

Comment: What do you mean by "off focus"?

Comment: When tab in which application is running goes off focus. for example I have my application in one tab, and then go to new tab with google in it